# Nested table doesn't fill parent td by height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, markup, html-table

I faced a problem with my markup in IE9+. Nested `table` doesn't fill the parent `td`.

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Crystall/fJ2WS/).
Red table must fill remaining vertical size.

In any other browser all is working fine.
Any help is appreciated.

---

**UPD.** Just added an image to show what I'm seeing in IE.

[image]

Comment: Is there really no other solution than using a nested table?

Comment: Yes, I can't apply any global changes to the markup. I hope that this problem can be resolved with pure CSS.

Comment: I did just try setting the `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` on both tables and [that worked](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ2WS/1/).  Just to add - it could be the `doctype` affecting it.

Comment: I don't see any difference in IE. http://db.tt/RArWifDT

Comment: Hmm.  LOL!  I can't even get Fiddle to work on my version of IE!  :D

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible to *fully* fill the space in CSS alone, but collapsing the border does help a bit:

```
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

[image: Example]

**Edit:** seems you've edited your question.

If both of your tables only ever have two rows, setting the `height` of the `td` elements to 50% seems to do the trick in IE:

```
table td {
    height:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fJ2WS/3/

Comment: No, both tables may have any count of rows.

Comment: Do they *have* to have % heights?

Comment: I assume yes. But top `tr` of parent table may have `px` size.